# Converting a grammar into LL(1) grammar: some problems

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, compiler-theory

This is not exactly homework but it is related to my studies:

A grammar for example is like:

> E -> E+E|E*E|-E|(E)|id

After removing ambiguity it becomes (starting from lowest precedence operator)

```
E->-F|F
F->F+G|G
G->G*H|H
H->(E)|id
```

And after removing the left recursion and left factoring (not needed in this case) the final LL1 grammar is:

```
E->-F|F
F->GF'
F'->+GF'|e
G->HG'
B->*HG'|e
H->(E)|id
```

Which gives an error free parser table which works fine.
Now about the problem I am facing, suppose the grammar is like this:

> E -> E+E|E*E|id=E|(E)|id

Now I am not able to generate a parsing table without conflicts, which means my final grammar is not LL1. Here are the steps:

after removing ambiguity:

```
E->id=F|F
F->F+G|G
G->G*H|H
H->(E)|id
```

And after removing the left recursion and left factoring, the grammar becomes:

```
E->id=F|F
F->GF'
F'->+GF'|e
G->HG'
B->*HG'|e
H->(E)|id
```

But there is a conflict in the Parser table that I am not able to remove, which means that there is some step that I have missed, or there is some mistake in the steps that I am not able to find. Please tell me what I have done wrong, and how to fix this. I have been working on this problem for a long time now.

Comment: Unary Minus operator precedence is not lowest, it's highest always on other binary operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that:

```
E -> E+E|E*E|id=E|(E)|id
```

will become:

```
E -> E+E|E*E|(E)|E'
E' -> id=E|id
```

then you can go with removing ambiguity and left-hand recursion and get:

```
E -> GF       FIRST(E) = FIRST(G)
F -> +GF|e
G -> HG'      FIRST(G) = FIRST(H)
G' -> *HG'|e
H -> (E)|E'   FIRST(H) = {(} + FIRST(E') = {(, id} 
E' -> idE''   FIRST(E') = {id}
E'' -> =E|e   FIRST(E'') = {=} + {#}
```

Of course, the problem is, that you lose the given operator precedence.

The **grammar won't be LL(1) if** for any nonterminal `N`, there will be **any common elements** in `FIRST(N -> a)` and `FIRST(N -> b)` for `N -> a`, `N -> b` being different productions from `N`.

As you see, adding a production `N -> id=` in **any other place would break that rule**.

You can create a `LL(2)` grammar (but this is probably not what you want), which can have `id=E` production at any place. (`FIRST2` sets are consisted of 2-element strings).

Also, if you look at the presented grammar one more time:

```
E -> E+E|E*E|id=E|(E)|id
```

It's a high chance, that the operator precedence I made in the solution above is the right one for real application. Check it out!